# Book with two boys and a girl who get powers from a book

Tags: story-identification, books

So the main character had powers over gravity, the girl could put electricity into metal like pennies and would throw them, the other boy had power over friction I think

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you recall any details of the setting (modern? victorian? mediaeval?) or antagonists?  What kind of tricks did the heroes do with their powers?

Comment: And how did they get their powers from a book? Was it a magical book? One with an explanation of how to build a machine to give them powers? One that provided a contract with Other Powers whereby they could get powers? Was there a virus or nanobot infection hibernating in the book?

Answer (score 4):

I found it, it’s called *[Simon Bloom, The Gravity Keeper](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1879966.Simon_Bloom_The_Gravity_Keeper)* by Michael Reisman.

> Sixth-grader Simon Bloom can't believe his luck when he finds a book that enables him to control the laws of physics. By simply reciting the formulas it contains, he can cancel gravity to fly around his bedroom, or decrease friction so he can slide down the street as if he were on Rollerblades. When two thugs with evil intentions come after Simon, he must use the formulas to save himself and the book from falling into their hands.

The main character Simon and his friends are exploring the forest when they see a group of people almost like a cult. They watch them and when the cult leaves there is a book left behind; it’s a teachers edition of a physics book. In it there are formulas that give them powers, one over friction, one over gravity, and one over electricity. The main villain is a female with a bunch of formulas tattooed all over her body.

Comment: Hey, it's great that you found it!  Since you have it, can you add some more details about it, even if it's just the blurb text?

Comment: Sure, so a the main character Simon and his friends are exploring the forest when they see a group of people almost like a cult, they watch them and when the cult leaves there is a book left behind, it’s teachers edition of a physics book, in it there are formulas that give them powers, one over friction, one over gravity, and one over electricity. The main villain is a female with a bunch of formulas tattooed all over her body